# Could not install from "@Angular\cli" as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: node.js, angular

Could not install from `@Angular\cli` as it does not contain a `package.json` file. I am getting this error  while running `npm install -g @Angular\cli` command

Comment: Try `npm install -g @angular/cli` ('/' instead of '\' and only lowercase letters)

Comment: Its `npm install -g @angular/cli`, wrong '/'

Answer (score 2):

you should first install @angular/cli globally `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: I am getting this error message: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ECONNABORTED

Comment: please turn off antivirus and try again. Which IDE are you using ? Run it as administrator.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off Real-Time protection of your Antivirus and try again. It will work